# How to decrypt the corrupt SD card formatted as internal storage?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, external-sd, file-system, encryption, adoptable-storage

So I'm on Marshmallow and have formatted my SD card as internal storage. Its filesystem got corrupt two weeks later for some reason.

Plugging it to GParted, I see 16MB of FAT32 and the rest is an unrecognized filesystem. It's not unformatted, just unrecognized.

GParted is giving the **"Unable to read the contents of the fileystem."** error for both partitions, though the FAT32 partition is accessible from File Browser flawlessly.

It's a Samsung i9505 running on nightly built Cyanogenmod 13.

EDIT: I found out the unrecognized partitions is a static AES-128 bit encrypted ext4. Now I will try to decrypt it and recover whatever.

EDIT2: I changed my mind and won't bother. Formatting as external storage this time.

Comment: How common is this?

Comment: [How to decrypt Adopted Storage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/145443/218526)

Answer (score 10):

Even it does not fully answer the question, here's a [guide](http://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2015/06/decrypting-android-m-adopted-storage.html) to decrypt the external storage formatted as internal. You do need to be root on your phone, however.

The gist is that we search for strings including the keyword `expand` and ending with `.key` within `vold` using:

```
$ strings vold|grep -i expand
--change-name=0:android_expand
%s/expand_%s.key
/mnt/expand/%s
```

It returns a 16-byte key.

```
expand_8838e738a18746b6e435bb0d04c15ccd.key
```

Then you pass the key into this bad boy:

```
# dmsetup create crypt1 --table "0 `blockdev --getsize /dev/sdb2` crypt \
aes-cbc-essiv:sha256 00010203040506070809010a0b0c0d0e0f 0 /dev/sdb2 0"
```

And mount that in:

```
# mount -t ext4 /dev/mapper/crypt1 /mnt/1/
# cd /mnt/1
# find ./ -type d
```

Now you can `cp` everything elsewhere and hopefully save some data. Remember to exclude any key-related data (`grep`) when doing so, in case you want to reformat as ınternal again and put your stuff back in.

Comment: You can use `hexdump -e '1/1 "%.2x"' expand_8838e738a18746b6e435bb0d04c15ccd.key` to convert binary to hex.

Comment: Where exactly do you run those command?

Comment: @Royi You plug your SD card to a Linux computer.

Comment: To be exact, the expanded storage key of named `expand_8838e738a18746b6e435bb0d04c15ccd.key` (the actual hex number depends on your expanded storage device) needs to be fetched or read from the phone. The file is usually located in directory `/data/misc/vold` and the directory may contain multiple keys if multiple SD cards have been used. Note that you have to have `root` access to your phone to see the contents of the key files and extract the required encryption key.