# How to expands sd-card formatted as internal storage?

Tags: internal-storage, external-sd, 6.0-marshmallow, formatting, adoptable-storage

In Android 6 I [formatted my 32GB sd card as internal storage](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/137855/how-does-the-format-as-internal-storage-feature-work-in-android-6-0).
What I now see with GParted on my desktop is this:
[image: GParted]

As you see there is still an unencrypted, readable FAT32 partition.
I assume it was created when formatting this sd card, because there I still had some large ZIPs (previously used for flashing) on my sd card.
I am a bit surprised to see that the data is still there - especially as the guide when formatting the sd card clearly states all data will be removed.
Possibly the files are also added afterwards as I used TWRP to copy some files to `/external_sd` even after I did this.

So I deleted the unnecessary ZIPs on my PC and now I obviously have unused space on my sd card. So: **How can I expand my sd card?**

It is also interesting what [Nemo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nemo_%28file_manager%29) shows me:
[image: NemoLinux]

The yellow parts are the used space (98,3 kB) and the blue on is empty (31,4 GB). It also claims the file system would be *msdos*...

Just FYI: Besides my ZIPs there are also empty folders called "Android" and "LOST.DIR".

Comment: FYI: The `LOST.DIR` is always created on FAT partitions (by/for `chkdsk`). And do you really bother for that small amount of storage? Wouldn't make that much difference I'd say. Also not sure if it maybe *must* be there (the formatting process might have its reasons to leave it). As for reading the partition with the "unknown file system" ("unbekannt") on your PC, you might wish to see [Corrupt SD card formatted as internal storage](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/135803/16575).

Comment: Yeah, I am more curios about what caused this than worried about the "lost" space. At least it are 16 MB.
Thanks for the FYI BTW.

Comment: Additionally theoretically another user could have the same "problem" with a larger FAT32 partition. I assume it depends on the files you previously had stored on the sd card or you later stored on the sd card.

Comment: I thought of that, yes. But it's purely hypotetical. Formatting as internal storage is an automated process, nothing a user does "with accidentally wrong parameters". But sure, the "why" is an interesting point, and may offer additional insight into the process/feature.

Comment: You have a 32GB card, and not a 64GB as it feels as per question heading.If you are running gparted in linux you can unmount and delete the little 16mb patrition.

Comment: @IftekharAS Ah yes, 32GB obviously. I changed that.
With GParted I could probably delete this partition, but I am not entirely sure whether this will work (and it is still recognized by Android afterwards).

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing exactly I believe that Android 5.0 and newer has gone and caused protection on orphaned memory space.  I would like to know more about situations like this.