# Why can I move apps to sd card when using adopted internal storage (sd card)? Does it makes sense?

Tags: external-sd, 6.0-marshmallow, app2sd, adoptable-storage

I formatted my sd card as [adopted internal storage](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/137855/how-does-the-format-as-internal-storage-feature-work-in-android-6-0) as possible in Android 6.

However in the settings I can still move (some) apps to the "external storage".
This is quite confusing as I thought they would be automatically placed on my sd card as this sd card is my "fake internal storage".

So I have three questions:

- Why can I still move them there?
- Where are they moved exactly to?
  Currently I noticed that the app data was stored in `/storage/emulated/0` respectively `/sdcard` (which is a symbol link to `/storage/emulated/0`)
- Does it make sense to move the apps like this?

Comment: That's an interesting question indeed. Is your device rooted, so you can check where such an app goes to? I have a suspicion here: App2SD doesn't necessarily move to the *external* SD card (the physical one), but to the "primary external storage", which usually is the *internal* SD card if such exists. Your mentioning of `/storage/emulated/0` seems to confirm this: "emulated" is the internal card. So if that's the case here, it indeed makes sense, as that "internal card" usually is a bit faster :)

Comment: Yes I have root. However as I mentioned AFAIK there is a symbolic link from `/sdcard` to `/storage/emulated/0` and this is the polace where the app data seem to be saved by default.

However I don't exactly know where the apps itself (the apks?) are saved. Which directories should I check?

Comment: APKs usually go to `/data/apps` on internal storage. App2SD would store them in a hidden folder on the SDCard (`.android_secure`). And as I already wrote: Yes, that's the emulated/internal SDCard your `/sdcard` symlink points to – and I suspect that's the target here. So you could use your "root powers" to check for the folder there: make yourself root (running `su` in a terminal/shell) and then do an `cd /sdcard && ls -a` (the hidden folder will be shown to root only).

Comment: Okay, `ls -a` there only shows my usual "internal storage" content. There is no folder called `.android_secure`.
However when booting into my recovery (TWRP) I noticed that in `external_sd` there are some directories: `app`, `local`, `media`, `misc` and `user`. And `app` indeed contains my apllication I moved to the sdcard.

Comment: App2SD never moves apps completely, so it is to be expected something remained in your internal/adopted storage. Strange however you cannot find any hidden directory on the internal SD card, which is what App2SD would use here. I know the system tries to hide it, but it shouldn't hide it from root. Could you check for `/mnt/secure/asec`, which should be the equivalent (`asec` is the abbreviated form of `android_secure`)?

Comment: `/mnt/secure/asec` is empty.

Comment: OK, then I'm out of ideas, sorry.