# How to replace a microSD card formatted as internal storage?

Tags: backup, adoptable-storage

I've got a Motorola Moto G 2 with Android 6 Marshmallow and an old microSD 8Go formatted as internal storage. Today, I would like to replace it with a new one, bigger and faster one.

BUT, I would like to save all the content (especially some app content, etc.)

Usually (with non formatted as internal storage cards) I switch off the phone, remove the SD card and copy it's whole content. But this time, the phone has to be running and thus, some folders (especially "Android") cannot be copied.

Will I lose come content ? Can I make a copy of this folder ?

Comment: You have to "unadopt" the SD card by switching it to portable storage, then insert the new card and adopt it. Not clean or easy, especially if you don't have enough space on your internal memory to copy everything from the old card to temporarily.

Comment: @acejavelin wouldn't that destroy the contents? Apart from which: the very same thing has just been asked yesterday: [How can I move data from an adopted SD card to a new SD card?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/141319/16575) (PS, Crypto: Also see our [adoptable-storage tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adoptable-storage/info). As one of the cons, it lists: *no "simple upgrade" to another (bigger, healthier, faster) SD card.*)

Comment: @Izzy It all depends on the amount of space on internal storage, the process tries to move it there if there is enough space, but generally there isn't. There isn't really a clean way to do this, since once an SD card is adopted another one cannot be until it is "unadopted", so using the mount in Linux trick (http://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2015/06/decrypting-android-m-adopted-storage.html) is tough. Personally, I think this is just another hole in the mess that is "adopted storage"

Comment: Thanks, @acejavelin! So basically you don't lose data if the amount on the adopted card fits on the "real internal storage" – in which case you'd probably not adopted it in the first place? So e.g. backing up enough apps+data (e.g. via `adb backup`) and removing that, so the remains fit, one could safely "unadopt" the card without data loss, adopt a new one, and restore the backups?

Comment: Honestly... You best and cleanest bet is to backup everything you can, unadopt the storage, factory reset (yeah, I know, it sucks), insert the new card and adopt it and set it as the default for everything, then reinstall/restore data. It is the cleanest, you can try skipping the factory reset part, but I always say to be prepared to do so whenever making a major change, if problems arise, do it.