# Properly migrate to larger SD card on Android 6.0?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, external-sd

I've got a Samsung S5 (T-Mobile SM-G900T)that's rooted on Android 6.0.1 and I want to upgrade my 64GB card to a 128GB one.

There are a few reasons I don't think a simple copy and paste will work:

The SD card itself has a unique name now (6CAB-391A). Any new SD card I put in will have a different name.

I've used the built-in feature of moving apps to external storage in Android. I have quite a few apps that have been moved off of "Internal Storage" and into "UsbStorage" using Application Manager > [app name] > Storage.

My SD card has not been adopted as internal storage. It's still labeled as an "external SD card" and has not been encrypted. There is also no option to migrate.

I suspect that a simple copy and paste will break a LOT of links and my apps will no longer work.

So what's the proper procedure on Android Marshmallow to migrate to a larger card?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I move data from an adopted SD card to a new SD card?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/141319/how-can-i-move-data-from-an-adopted-sd-card-to-a-new-sd-card)

Comment: *Move App to External Storage* is a feature of [tag:adoptable-storage], hence marked it as duplicate.

Comment: My SD card has not been adopted. It's still an "external SD card" and has not been encrypted. There is also no option to migrate.

Comment: Ok. Retracted close vote but you mentioned in your Q that you *moved app to external storage using inbuilt feature*- strange, since that is not a Marshmallow feature AFAIK except for adoptable-storage. Anyway, you can follow the steps in that answer or if your internal storage didn't have space, use Titanium Backup and restore data of those apps on external SD

Comment: I did. I have quite a few apps that have been moved off of "Internal Storage" and into "UsbStorage" using Application Manager > [app name] > Storage. I'm using Marshmallow 6.0.1. But my microUSB has definitely not been adopted as local storage.

Comment: Well, I am also on same version (Moto X Play) and pretty sure that option disappeared from Lollipop. Please mention your device also in question and hope you get an answer soon

Comment: Looks like it is Samsung specific- see this http://android.stackexchange.com/q/138356/131553