# SD card not showing files when connected to pc in Moto G3

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, adoptable-storage

I convert the sd card (32GB) from portable storage to internal storage but now when I connect to computer, it only show internal storage (8GB). How can I copy thing to my "sd card" from computer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the "Format as internal storage" feature work in Android 6.0+?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/137855/how-does-the-format-as-internal-storage-feature-work-in-android-6-0)

Comment: You can't (at least not without root). You have no "SD card" anymore, as it was adopted as internal storage. See the question Aaron linked, and also take a look at our [adoptable-storage tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adoptable-storage/info).

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug in the Moto G3 when adopting storage as internal or when using external storage after an update (or other random times)... When you connect your Moto G3 to your computer and enable MTP mode, you should see two "drives", one that is internal (your SD card) and one external (your old internal storage). Without consistency, some users report the old internal storage never shows up, but the SD card acting as internal storage should regardless.

Start by rebooting and [clearing cache partition](https://motorola-mobility-en-in.custhelp.com/app/answers/prod_answer_detail/a_id/105656/p/30,6720,9390). Motorola says this will take 5-10 minutes, I assume they tested this on a bare device with no apps or other information just fresh out of the box, because it takes significantly longer. Also, the device will appear frozen, this is normal, be patient and wait. It will take a significant amount of time in recovery, and in the first boot, this is normal.

If that doesn't work, then the storage and media databases need to be wiped and rebuilt.

1. Disconnect USB cable
2. Go to `Settings` - `Apps`
3. Tap 3-Dot overflow menu and select `Show system`
4. Scroll down and select the app called `External Storage`
5. Inside `External Storage` select `Storage`
6. Inside `Storage` tap `Clear cache` and `Clear data`
7. Go back to the app list and scroll down to `Media Storage`
8. Repeat steps 5&6 with `Media Storage` app
9. Reboot the device
10. After it is fully booted and appears functional, wait a minimum of 5 minutes (media and storage cache's are rebuilding automatically)
11. Connect USB cable and using the notification drop-down menu, select `USB Charging - Touch for more options` and select `Transfer Files (MTP)`

This should give you access to both storage media via your PC, it has always worked for me and I have had to do it a few times, but I use Linux. Not that some users have not been able to make this work in Windows, it seems that in some instances Windows get's, for lack of a better word, dumb with MTP devices sometimes.

If all this fails, then the action of last resort is a full factory default, skip setup, adopt storage, and verify operation, then set up the device again. If this fails, the problem isn't likely the device, but the computer.