# Split external SD card partially into adoptable storage and portable storage

Tags: external-sd, adoptable-storage

I don't want all my external SD card as adopted/internal storage, so I was wondering how I can split it into 1 part adopted storage and 1 part normal file storage (what Android calls "portable storage").

Answer (score 26, accepted):

*You don't need to root your device but the device i done this with is rooted*

1. You need to enabled Developer Options.
2. Enable the USB Debugging option.
3. Make sure your SD card is formatted as portable, then get the `adb` executable (see our [adb tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adb/info) for details).
4. Connect your device to your PC and run the `adb devices` command. If your device is connected correctly you will see your device listed in the output.
5. Run `adb shell sm list-disks adoptable`. This will show you the list of disks that can be used for what we want.
6. For my device it showed me `disk:179,128` so i ran `adb shell sm partition disk:179,128 mixed 80` on my 32 GB AS card. It gave me 5 GB as adoptable storage and the rest for other uses. (This will format your SD card.)

Comment: Does this really require root as the command to set up adoptive storage in the 1st place does not? (sm partition disk:foo,bar)

Comment: @Barleyman Well not really but my device is rooted and i didn't test this with none rooted devices so if you like you can try and let me know if you got any error

Comment: I did actually yesterday and today on my Galaxy S5. I didn't use the mixed type but at least the *sm partition disk:foo,bar private* works just fine without root. Migrating from lollipop with Link2SD to Marshmallow with adoptable storage is a bit of work. Gotta do clean install and copy titanium backup files to PC & back and repartition the sdcard on pc and later on the phone. Also titanium backup does not realize phone storage is running out so you'll have to fight past dialogs to move a single app to sdcard to make enough room that you can use apps2sd to migrate the rest..

Comment: Works perfectly on Moto E with CM13 Temasek 10.4. Thanks!

Comment: On my device the `sm partition disk: disk:179,128 mixed 80` command returned the *usage* of the command, maybe it's because of the custom ROM, but I replaced the *comma with an underscore* and it accepted it - eg. `sm partition disk: disk:179_128 mixed 80`

Comment: I searched far and wide to come to this resolution... Was able to follow steps using terminal emulator directly on rooted phone, **without using adb or usb phone connection**: - Format internal SD as portable in settings, hit eject (unmount), opened terminal emulator, I `su` (just incase) to become root, then `sm list-disks adoptable`, found my storage `179_64`, then `sm partition disk:179_64 mixed 80`. It immediately started working. Ignored format prompt. Then rebooted and all prompts asking if I wanted to format went away.

Answer (score 4):

[poqdavid's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/145458/44325) is correct.

In addition though, you might get the error that your SD card on your device storage is corrupted. If so, follow these steps.

After you have partitioned the disk and while your SD card is corrupted, enter the following commands in the terminal which will list your volumes, for example:

```
$> adb shell sm list-volumes all
private mounted null
public:179,1 mounted B5B1-140C
private:179,3 unmountable null
emulated mounted null
```

Then enter the following replacing `179,3` with whichever disk numbers you are given:

```
$> adb shell sm format private:179,3
$> adb shell sm mount private:179,3
```

Now your SD card in device storage should be properly mounted and your portable storage will still be there.

This worked on my LG G5 and should work on the Samsung Galaxy S7.

Comment: i tried 3 four time $>adb shell sm format private:179,3
$> adb shell sm mount private:179,3 $> sm list-volumes all  output;_private mounted null public:179,1 mounted 5C8A-85AC  private:179,3 unmountable  emulated;0 mounted why it showing unmountable , can we conver 179,3 to public or mount from other adb shell mount command to