# Split adopted storage doesn't work

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, adoptable-storage

I have a HTC One M8 and I split my adopted storage with adb like this:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10586]
(c) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>adb shell
shell@htc_m8:/ $ sm set-force-adoptable true
shell@htc_m8:/ $ sm list-disks
disk:179,32
shell@htc_m8:/ $ sm partition disk:179,32 mixed 80
shell@htc_m8:/ $ sm list-disks adoptable
disk:179,32
```

It seems to work, no error, and the phone shows the SD card as internal and external, but both as "beschädigt" - it doesn't work.

So I have to format one partition with the phone. And the result is, either the whole space of the SD card is internal or external; it depends on which part I choose to format.

Is there any help for this problem?

Comment: Related: [How to split adopted storage?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/145457/16575) Note that `list-disks` gave you `173,29` according to your question, but you ran `partition disk` with `179,32` which doesn't match. Moreover, shouldn't you have used `sm list-disks adoptable` (note the additional parameter)?

Answer (score 1):

You are entering the wrong disk. The numbers are wrong and you have a space after the "**:**".

This is the correct command:

```
sm partition disk:173,29 mixed 80
```

Or this (I don't know your disk number..)

```
sm partition disk:179,32 mixed 80
```

---

If both commands don't work, please post a screenshot of the output of this command: `sm list-disks`.

Comment: But in the question I write it wrong: I have no space between "...disk:17..." SORRY

Comment: @Dawe Can you post the exact output of `sm list-disks`, please? With copy/paste or screenshot?

Comment: I edit the question... Now theres the copied text....