# How can I enable adoptable storage and get my Samsung Galaxy on5 to use my external SD card as it's Internal Memory?

Tags: rooting, adoptable-storage

I may have @ the time I put my SD card in originally but I don't recall ever coming across that feature/option. Also, I definitely do not wanna erase/reformat my 128 GB SD card (that's about 3/4 full) to be able to see if that's is/was ever given as an option when putting a brand-new card.

If ANYONE'S able to offer me ANY advice/ideas, tips/tricks, choices/options on this matter as well as ROOTING and/or UNLOCKING for my Samsung Galaxy on5 SM-G550T2 phone.

Comment: What is version of android your phone running?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SD card as both internal and external storage without rooting.

Infact there is already and answer here in SE in how to do just that:

https://android.stackexchange.com/a/145458/127015

I would strongly recommend you backup your SD card, just in case.