# How can I ensure that files such as photos/videos are stored in the SD card in Android Marshmallow?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, internal-storage, external-sd, lenovo, adoptable-storage

I have a Lenovo Vibe K4 Note phone with Android 6.0 Marshmallow. I have formatted my SD card as internal storage. As a result, when I view the file system either through my phone or my PC, both the real internal storage and the SD card appear logically combined under Internal Storage.

I have many apps installed, such as Google apps, that do not allow me to move them to the SD card portion of the logical internal storage, and hence reside in the "real" internal storage only (but that is not my question).

The problem is that when I take pictures or videos, they are also stored in the "real" internal storage. Now, my internal storage gets very quickly filled up, while my SD card is near empty. Moreover, as logically both appear in the file manager as one "Internal Storage" category combined, I am not able to figure out how to move out the images from the real internal storage to the SD Card.

My questions are:

1. When SD Card is formatted as internal storage in Marshmallow, how can I enforce that certain files are stored in the SD Card? How can I ensure that new photos are stored in the SD Card?
2. How can I move existing files from the real internal storage to the SD Card?

Comment: @beeshyams Could you please elaborate, maybe as an answer? Thanks.

Comment: @beeshyams Done

Comment: [this is one option](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/145457/131553)