# Where can I get more information on the sm tool (command) used in the Terminal

Tags: terminal

I have seen the `sm` tool used a few places for example [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/145457/i-want-to-split-one-microsd-card-into-two-parts-part-adoptable-storage-and-par).

The way I understand it, it is a storage management tool but I haven't been successful in finding any more info about it.

Where can I find more information on this tool?

Comment: See if you can understand the source code here:  https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/cmds/sm/src/com/android/commands/sm/Sm.java

Comment: I'm not much familiar with code is there anything else available? Does Google/Android have info anywhere?

Comment: @Firelord I started looking into the code link you gave. I'm looking to figure out how to use the command `sm forget UUID` I'm not sure what the `UUID` is. When I do `sm forget all` I do accomplish what I'm looking for but I'm not sure what other devices its forgetting in the process. The source shows that its `import android.os.storage.IStorageManager` but I can't seem to find the code for this `IStorageManager` anywhere.

Comment: UUID is the identifier of a a storage device. http://go2linux.garron.me/linux/2010/09/uuid-linux-fstab-file-766/

Comment: @Firelord OK I took a look there but what I'm facing is that when I run `blkid` I get for my external SD card the same number that identifies the card under `/storage`. When I tried using this number in `sm forget UUID` it didn't work. From what I read from the link you provided it seems this isn't the actual `UUID`. How can I get the `UUID`? The options given on that link didn't help me. As I mentioned `blkid` gives me just the ID not the `UUID` and there is no `/dev/disk/by-uuid/` for me to run `ls -l` on.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm busy in some other work, so I cannot provide assistance for a while.

Answer (score 0):

The `sm` tool is not an Android tool, it's a [linux shell command](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sm).  Android devices have some shell commands located in `/system/bin` - the variety of these usually vary by version, OEM, and platform.

You can issue this `adb` command to see what tools are available:

```
adb shell ls system/bin
```

You can ask for help on each tool - for example, with `sm`:

```
$ adb shell sm -help
usage: sm list-disks [adoptable]
       sm list-volumes [public|private|emulated|all]
       sm has-adoptable
       sm get-primary-storage-uuid
       sm set-force-adoptable [true|false]
       sm set-virtual-disk [true|false]

       sm partition DISK [public|private|mixed] [ratio]
       sm mount VOLUME
       sm unmount VOLUME
       sm format VOLUME
       sm benchmark VOLUME
       sm fstrim

       sm forget [UUID|all]

       sm set-emulate-fbe [true|false]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I'm looking for is a little more info on the options for this command. I have already done the help but I'm still no clear on what all the options do, or how they work.