# please explain the: >"adb shell sm partition disk:179,64 mixed 80" command

Tags: adb, partitions, command-line, ab-partition

it is taken from [I want to split one MicroSD card into two parts: part adoptable storage, and part normal storage. How can I do this?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/145457/i-want-to-split-one-microsd-card-into-two-parts-part-adoptable-storage-and-par)

what is 80 at the end? 80%?

I ran that on an Adoptable Storage card and it erased many installed programs :/ lesson learned 
https://www.reddit.com/r/MotoG/comments/g7n3ye/fyi_do_you_want_to_expand_your_internal_storage/

Comment: *"WARNING - DO THIS ON A fresh / formatted microSD - else this will erase your Adoptable Storage data, pictures, applications"* according to linked question 5 GB ÷ 32 GB = 15% (+ 5% reserved) 80 means = [adoptable-storage](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adoptable-storage/info) ~ 20% + external Storage ~ 80%