# I'm having trouble identifying the SD Card on OnePlus Nord 200 5G for partition and format

Tags: adb, sd-card, partitions, formatting

I recently got myself a OnePlus Nord 200 5G running Android 11 and I'm trying to format my SD card. The problem is that I can't identify the card in ADB shell. From the shell:

```
OnePlusN200TMO:/ $ sm list-disks
disk:179,0
OnePlusN200TMO:/ $ sm list-volumes all
emulated:179,2;0 unmounted null
private mounted null
private:179,2 mounted a0104c1c-c041-4496-9c7d-aa584d166a71
emulated;0 mounted null
```

So is the 179,0 the internal and 179,2 the SD? If so, and I want to format like half or 2/3 as internal and the remaining as external (256 GB SD) how would I do that? I'm being extra careful because I have seen posts that bricked the phone.

Comment: disk:179,0 is the disk MicroSD Card and private:179,2 is the partition MicroSD Card. you already adopted 100% and will lose apps and pictures on repartition (no root required) https://android.stackexchange.com/q/224372

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't do that without root access

Comment: Thank you, that's one thing I needed to know.

Comment: no root required