# How to format SD card second partition as internal storage

Tags: sd-card, storage, android-10

I formatted my SD card into 2 partition. The first one is `exfat` and the second partition is `f2fs`.

I want to format the second partition as internal storage using built in storage setting, but when I do that the whole SD card get formatted.

How do I format the second partition as internal storage without losing the first partition data?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I want to split one MicroSD card into two parts: part adoptable storage, and part normal storage. How can I do this?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/145457/i-want-to-split-one-microsd-card-into-two-parts-part-adoptable-storage-and-par)

Comment: I will lose my data that way

Comment: yes repartitioning will erase everything. do a backup to PC via adb and restore afterwards. no other way because adoptable-storage requires 3rd partition 16 MiB (probably related to encryption)

Comment: okay thanks @alecxs I'll test it using my another SD card.