# Resize USB internal storage and use some as external without formatting the whole USB

Tags: adb, partitions, ab-partition, amazon-fire-tv

I expanded my Amazon FireTV 4K Max (Fire TV Home Version 6341067.1 running Fire OS 7.2.5.5 PS7255/2444) storage by installing a USB flash drive together with an OTG and a usb 3.0 hub but i formatted the whole USB as internal storage.

I would like to know if is it possible to resize the USB partition used as internal storage so i canuse the rest of the USB as external storage without having to format the whole USB?

Hope someone can help.

Thanks in advanced. :)

Comment: Possible dupe: [I want to split one MicroSD card into two parts: part adoptable storage, and part normal storage. How can I do this?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/145457/44325)? Though, not sure if it can be done without formatting the whole USB.

Comment: It's no dupe because I'm asking for possible resize without losing the information in the already created partition.