# Cloning encrypted ext4 partition

Tags: sd-card, internal-sd, adoptable-storage, ext4

I have a micro SD card adopted by an Android 8 Oreo phone as internal storage extension, so it has two encrypted ext4 partitions: android_meta and android_expand. I've cloned those partitions into the "far end" of a bigger card using Macrium Reflect 8 (selecting the byte by byte copy mode w/o any analysis and optimization if I got it right) and created "external" aka "portable" partition in its free space later so that it goes first (just to please Windows). I also cloned the GUID. Unfortunately my phone is reporting "Adopted missing" upon booting up with it. What else am I missing? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shrinking encrypted ext4 partition](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/251686/shrinking-encrypted-ext4-partition)

Comment: @alecxs it definitely helps explain my issues with it: much appreciated! Looks like my phone wants entire card encrypted, hence no chance with dual partitioning I suppose.