# Unexpected "insufficient memory" warning w/ adopted SD card

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, insufficient-memory, adoptable-storage

According to this [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/137855/how-does-the-format-as-internal-storage-feature-work-in-android-6-0/137857#137857), I expected to get 64GB internal storage by adopting 100% of 64GB SD card to 32GB phone.
Though I've got the warning when total data size reach to 32GB.

Please let me know what I should do to expand the internal storage.

#### Steps I tried

1. Run following command.

   ```
   adb shells
   sm list-disks
   sm partition DISK private
   ```

   - No setup wizard starts. It adopt SD card silently....
2. Go Setting > Storage to make sure the SD belongs to Internal Storage.
3. Reboot the device.
4. Go Setting > App. And made apps to store in "SD card".
5. DL contents through app.

#### Current Storage Status

- Setting > Storage > Internal Storage section

  - Internal: 31.99GB
  - SD: 0.3MB
- Setting > Storage > Internal Storage section > each detail page

  - Internal: 9GB
  - SD: 23GB

Comment: See [this answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/137857/131553) and more in [tag:adoptable-storage] tag ( which you have correctly chosen as a tag tp your question). This answer will explain why *I was expecting to get 32GB(default) + 64GB(100% of SD) internal storage* is a wrong expectation

Comment: Thx for suggesting me the answer @beeshyams . Though I still am confused.... Now I understand the adoptable storage not just plus storage size, like the answer saying you get 32GB if you have 8GB phone and 32GB SD. If so, shouldn't it be 64GB as my SD sized? Or is it limited upto 32GB for every SD?

Comment: To my limited understanding (not having used it nor intending to given all these complications) it should be  64 GB. Also read all the comments on the answer and the answer below that to help you understand better. If you still are confused, edit your question by referring to those answers and ask your question to clear. As I understand now, with better understanding, even now, the question can be edited

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution.

It is the "migrate data" function.

You need to go Setting > Storage > SD card of internal storage, then run "migrate data" function inside the right top menu after running commands.

I didn't do this because I want to put just certain apps to the SD card,
but seems like I can't.