# What happens to the already existing internal storage memory if I make SD card my internal storage marshamallow

Tags: internal-storage, 6.0-marshmallow, sd-card, internal-sd, adoptable-storage

I recently bought a phone (Lava P7) and upgraded it to Marshmallow. I need more internal memory space so I thought to make SD card my Internal storage. My SD card is 16Gb and internal storage is 8GB if I make SD card my Internal storage, then

My internal storage memory become 16+8 24Gb or 16Gb

if 16Gb, where does the already existing memory goes?

Comment: Your **total** available storage will be 16Gb, including internal storage. Please see [tag:adoptable-storage] tag ( which has been added to your question) to fully understand)

Comment: Related: [How does the “Format as internal storage” feature work in Android 6.0+?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/137855/16575) Quote: *if you had a phone with 8GB of storage and a 32GB microSD card, you’ll only have 32GB of space for music, movies, games, or other files, not 40GB*. [Another quote](http://www.greenbot.com/article/3039136/android/adoptable-storage-in-android-6-0-what-it-is-how-it-works.html): *Where before you might only have had 10-12GB of storage available on a “16GB” phone, you could have around 70GB if you adopt a 64GB microSD card.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that 3 GB of your internal storage is used by the system, leaving you with 5 GB of usable space, and your SD card is empty.

Currently, you have 5 GB usable for apps (internal storage) and 21 GB usable for media (both the internal storage and the SD card).  Note that the media storage will still be divided between the two storage locations, which makes it hard to manage.  Installing apps/app data will reduce the available space for *internal* media, and vice versa.

Under adoptable storage, you will have 21 GB for apps (internal storage + SD card) and 16 GB usable for media (SD card).  Note that each app is either fully on the internal storage, or fully on the adopted SD card.  Installing/moving apps and their data to the SD card will reduce the available space for media on the SD card, and vice versa.

Essentially, your choice is: Allow media to also be on the internal storage, or allow apps to also be on the SD card.  (Plus, in the latter case the SD card will no longer be accessible when removed from the device [unless decrypted](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/145443/1465).)  You cannot have both; both storage locations remain separate and are not combined into a single logical partition.  The only difference is what is "allowed" in each spot and how it can be accessed.

Please refer to [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/496sn3/lets_clear_up_the_confusion_regarding_storage_in/) for more background on how this works.

Comment: **Very Helpful** _great_