# Is it possible to use the SdCard in portable mode but encrypt it?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, external-sd, adoptable-storage

I dislike how the internal sdcard formating works, I don't want to replace the internal storage with my sdcard, my target would be to extend the storage.

Mainly, I use the sdcard as storage for the camera and personal data. I really want to encrypt this data.

Is it possible to use internal (for example 8gb) and external storage (64gb) resulting in 72gb total storage. accessing it via usb cable on the PC but not only encrypt the internal storage but also the external?

edit:

Extra question/Clearification:
I want encryption of the internal and external sd (no matter how its called "portable mode" or "internal mode"), keeping the sytem data and the apps on the fast internal sd but also have my data encrypted on the slow external sd. also i don't want to loose storage space, so it should be an "and" not an "or". is there some tutorial how to archive that? root access is available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible using the Android encryption of Marshmallow. *Disk Encryption* encompasses internal *and* external SD in the case of *adoptable-storage* and only *internal SD* in the case of *portable storage* ( since the external SD is considered a part of SD in the former)

[Full Disk Encryption](https://source.android.com/security/encryption/) mentions other possibilities of encryption and does not cover what you wish to achieve.

You may need to use a third party app, like [SSE universal encryption](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.paranoiaworks.unicus.android.sse), or other apps to encrypt files on external SD. I haven't tried this app but mentioning being open source and hence perhaps better

Comment: Extra question: you wrote that Full Disk Encryption does not meet my needs. I want encryption of the internal and external sd, keeping the sytem data and the apps on the fast internal sd but also have my data encrypted on the slow external sd. also i don't want to loose storage space, should be an "and" not an "or". is there some tutorial how to archive that? root access is available.

Comment: *I want encryption of the internal and external sd, keeping the sytem data and the apps on the fast internal sd but also have my data encrypted on the slow external sd*- this is what adopting an external SD card does BUT *I don't want to loose storage space* - this part is tricky. See this [What happens to the already existing internal storage memory if I make SD card my internal storage marshamallow](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/152308/131553) question and also read up on the comments to question and reddit post linked in answer

Comment: This site works best on single question and answer format, so if you don't get clarity, please ask a separate question, referring to the linked questions and see adoptable-storage *wiki* for more