# How to use micro sd card as internal memory on samsung galaxy tab A

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab, adoptable-storage

I was reading on google that you can make a tablet recognize micro sd card as internal memory? How can this be done on a Samsung Galaxy Tab (Model Number SM-t350) running Android version 6.0.1.

If it can be done what happens to the 16GB of internal storage currently being used. I would prefer not having to root my tablet due to the fact that I know nothing of rooting. All I want to accomplish is more memory for my tablet whether I download apps or put books on my tablet.

Comment: I think Samsung have not  implemented Adoptable Storage on its devices : http://forums.androidcentral.com/android-6-0-marshmallow/695816-galaxy-tab-2016-10-1-wi-fi.html, A rooted method described here for Tab S : https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-tab-s/general/patch-adoptable-storage-enabler-t3460478

Comment: To add to my answer, here is the answer to your second query i.e. **If it can be done what happens to the 16GB of internal storage currently being used.**    _Once a card has been formatted as internal storage, both the device internal storage and the card will show up as "device storage" under storage settings, and applications can be moved back and forth between the two._

Comment: So going buy this I can't upgrade my internal storage?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't find any default options available over settings which Chandrani Chatterjee posted, then you don't have any other option until you don't root your device.

Comment: So, how would you do it with a rooted device?

Answer (score 1):

To use your microSD card as internal storage follow these steps:

1) Insert the SD card in your device

2) Click on the notification saying SD card detected

3) Select setup

4) Choose **Use as Internal storage**

But please note that the microSD card needs to be formatted so as to use it as internal storage. So kindly back up files before doing so.

Also note that, using microSD card as internal storage has some cons.

1) It might slow down your device.

2) You can switch from using it as internal memory to portable memory, but it takes time and needs formatting again.

3) Your device will expect the adopted SD card to be always present and it will misbehave it the SD card is removed.

So, use your SD card as internal memory only if necessary.

Comment: 1. Please edit posts in totality ( including removing unnecessary tags and adding relevant tags )- in this case adoptable storage tag was relevant and added. 2. Your solution is not complete- OP asked what happens to device storage - see this for explanation http://android.stackexchange.com/q/152308/131553

Comment: Got it. Missed the second part of question.

Comment: OP is asking for a specific device, on which the default Android options are not available.