# Storage problem in Marshmallow

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, storage

Since the day I started using `format as internal` in marshmallow, my phone's ( Lenovo k4 note) memory is totally doomed. Everything I install goes only to the actual internal storage of the phone. There is no option to transfer stuff in the SD card. My phone always shows 'insufficient space' every time I try to download new stuff. Right now my internal memory says 0 bytes free of 10.3 GB and my SD card shows 8.7 GB free.

How can I use that? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Format as internal sets the SD card up in such a way that to apps it appears as internal storage, effectively replacing you internal storage:

[How does the "Format as internal storage" feature work in Android 6.0+?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/137855/how-does-the-format-as-internal-storage-feature-work-in-android-6-0)

So of course you internal storage appears full (As everything is now stored on the SD Card), and of course you have no options to move stuff to your SD Card (As everything is already there, and it is being used as internal storage).

Your SD Card is 16GB I'm guessing? Of which 7.3 is used up by apps, games, pictures, etc (Your 'internal storage'). Your internal storage is reported as full as it can't be used.