# Moto G 3rd Gen - SD Card stopped working

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, motorola-moto-g3

This morning my SD Card suddenly stopped working. As soon as I removed it and reinserted it, nothing happens. It does not even tell me to format it. I also tried to insert it in my PC but it says that it is corrupted and needs format.

If possible I'd like to avoid to format it since I've got all my photos on it.

The SD Card is a Samsung EVO 32 GB one, and it's also pretty new, since I bought it 2 months ago.

Does anyone have any clue of why this happens and a way to fix it?

Comment: If data on the SD card is corrupted, the only wait to use your card is to format it.

Comment: There is a way to access data on a card that can't be read in the Moto G 2015 with the use of another identical or larger card... sometimes... Try this: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/174799/moto-g3-android-marshmallow-not-detecting-sd-card-anymore-solution

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I only have the answer for the first part of your question. There are many reasons why an SD Card can go corrupt. (e.d. Physical Damage, not removing it properly etc.) As far as the latter is considered, Android has the option to eject the SD Card in Settings before you physically remove it from the phone. This option exists only to serve this one purpose, to stop things like this from happening (e.d. getting your SD Card corrupted).

I don't think there is much you can do at this point but reformat it, which of course as you probably know deletes all of your files.

**HOWEVER** do **NOT** reformat it still only because I am not familiar with any options of restoring it to proper function. I have heard of different types of software that claim they can do the thing for you, **BUT** be careful! As they are many of them that come in a form of some malware.