# SD formatted as internal storage got corrupted in a weird way on Android. Can I recover the data somehow?

Tags: root-access, 6.0-marshmallow, recovery-mode, adoptable-storage

So, I am not quite sure what happened. I'm on Android 6.0 and using an SD formatted as internal storage. Today, when I took a photo I realised it didn't save, and upon further inspections all the photos, videos and other media appear to be completely gone from the card. Those were backed up, so it's not a huge issue - the bigger problem are my Whatsapp logs which also appear to be missing. Whatsapp does a daily backup to Google Drive, but in my case it appears it backed up after the card got corrupted - and all the media are missing. I really need those backups.

Curiously, the card didn't get completely corrupted. All the apps installed on the card still work. Not quite sure what happened.

I realise that the internally-formatted microSD is encrypted and it can only be used on the original device... but I have access to that device. Is there any way at all for me to perform data recovery on that card? One issue I have is that this particular phone (Blackberry Priv) apparently can't be rooted.

I have read in a few sources (eg. [here](https://www.easeus.com/storage-media-recovery/how-to-recover-data-from-sd-card-formatted-as-internal-storage.html)) that re-formatting the card as portable from my phone would decrypt it and allow to do normal data recovery, but that seems somehow dubious.

I also found [this post](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/154696/recovering-data-from-corrupted-sd-card-formatted-as-internal-storage-marshmallo) that suggests that I should use dd to clone my microSD and see if it works, or to use a microUSB to microSD adapter. I have also thought about imaging the entire phone via ADB but would that work without root?

Comment: See [adoptable-storage tag wiki & questions](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adoptable-storage/info) for more info

Comment: you misunderstood. re-formatting won't in any way help you to recover data. dd would be useful only if you want to clone the (weared-out?) microSD to another microSD. sorry to say but your data is lost, you may have more luck to check for older google backups https://drive.google.com/drive/backups