# How to Read marshmallow encrypted memory card?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, adoptable-storage

Please help on this ..

I am using Marshmallow 6.0.1, in that i am using Memory card as internal storage. Unfortunately my mobile got stuck with booting.

Now, my most of the data are available in the memory card. so i took out the memory card and tried to read from other devices with windows system. But its failed

i googled about this, it says its difficult to read !. It would be really helpful if any one helped on this

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! Please take a look at our [adoptable-storage tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adoptable-storage/info) and follow up to [How to decrypt adopted storage?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/145443/16575) and [Corrupt SD card formatted as internal storage](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/135803/16575). Both mention solutions to read the card on a PC – provided you have root access on your device to grab the encryption key. Otherwise, you're lost.

Answer (score 0):

The SD Card will only be read from the device you set it to. 
I believe if you to a hard reset but keep the data where the key is stored intact, you can still use it regularly.
Take a look at this thread:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-e/general/trick-switching-roms-loosing-adopted-sd-t3314647