# Phone Reboots on Installing/Launching Certain Apps

Tags: applications, cyanogenmod, rooting, samsung, reboot

So i'm having this really baffling issue. I was using CM13 before and now using CM12 and both of them are facing the same issue.

I am using Galaxy Mega i9152.

There are certain applications, that have been causing my phone to reboot upon install or launch. Previously, it was Yahoo Mail (which i have not used since), then it was some other games (names of which i don't remember) and now it is WhatsApp messenger.

I thought the problem was with the CM13 rom, so i did a clean flash ( wiped data, cache, basically everything other than internal/external storage) of CM12 (hoping to get the 'move to SD card' feature as a bonus).

But, it did not resolve the issue. I just tried to install WhatsApp on my new ROM and it restarted as soon as WhatsApp finished Installing.

This has me thinking that the issue is not with Apps, but something to do with a deeper level. I'm not an expert in Kernels or such.

So please, can someone help me out here? Any insight i can get into the issue ?

WhatsApp is really important for managing day-to-day affairs, so please help me out.

Comment: Does it happen even without SD card installed? If the SD card had problems and would force a reboot every time it was accessed (happened to me had to change SD card  to fix). Probably the app is trying to access the SD card as a part of permissions given to it and it reboots ?

Comment: @beeshyams Odd, no? Failing to access an SD card should result in a warning at best, or a crash at worst.

Comment: Did you install the correct Gapps package, OP?

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman: Odd yes, after surrendering hours trying to fix it with every trick recommended in book, discovered this, when quite  by accident didn't insert SD card. It was a rooted Honor 6 , no Gapps, stock ROM and upgrading ROM didn't help. Pretty much like the situation with OP except for the Gapps angle ( which  you pointed out). Changed SD, it worked fine and I am still using that SD on my current device

Comment: @beeshyams , can you elaborate exactly why will the App write to SD card on CM13 ? I have not adopted the card as internal storage, i have been keeping it as portable ever since my first bootloop in April 2017, read [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/172347/recovering-data-from-adaptive-storage-while-phone-stuck-at-boot). So without adopting the SD card as internal, there is no reason for an app to write to SD card. Do correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman, yeah i always look at the version of the GApps before installing them. it matches my ROM in exact version numbers. I would switch phones but i will only have enough money after 3 months or so, need to keep going with this phone up till then. Do elaborate if you have any insight with regards to the SD card issue mentioned by beeshyams.

Comment: It doesn't need to write , it requires access permissions (let's say WhatsApp) , so I *guess* it checks and that triggers it. In my case  everytime I clicked storage in settings, it would reboot. This is a possibility and I am not sure if that is the case. If you can verify you can validate

Answer (score 1):

This could solve the problem temporarily. I had the same problem with my own phone and it appears to be a material problems, many recent updates are incompatible with some phones (it is the case for wiko phones).
Bypassig the play store and installing a previous update can work. For whatsapp you will need a previous version than the actual one (2.18.64), but that will be older than the 2.18.0, otherwise whatsapp won't let you start the app.

For example downloading this version and manually install worked for me: https://apkpure.com/whatsapp-business/com.whatsapp.w4b/download/164-APK

EDIT:

Now this version is considered obsolete by whatsapp too. The only way to continue using it for me was to set the date of my phone to a previous date that the date showed on whatsapp saying "This version of whatsapp is obsolete since date".

I hope this problem will be fixed later because it is unsafe to install previous versions, generally updates include bug and security fixes.

Comment: Can you please conclude, is this issue from Phone / OS / Application or what?
Sorry I might have lack of understanding, but I'm facing same issue, but I don't understand what is causing this problem to some of end users.