# internal storage showing up as 0MB

Tags: twrp, xiaomi, disk-encryption

I have a Redmi Note 7 (lavender)

As I was updating between custom ROM versions (Android 11) and the stock ROM (MIUI), I messed up a few things and ended up with broken encryption. The internal storage is showing up as 0MB, possibly due to this. I know the password, and when I enter it into TWRP's password scren, it shows it as being successful, but I'm getting the error: `Unable to mount storage`

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Your device was shipped with Android 9 which means that it is by default encrypted using the hardware security module. This module contains the key required for decrypting the data, therefore off-device encryption is impossible, sorry.

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/230892 most likely hopeless your only chance is TWRP

Comment: @Robert So how do I decrypt it within the device, then?

Comment: I don't know how to do this manually. Have you tried to install and use a recovery ROM with decryption feature (mostly TWRP should be able to decrypt the user data partition)?

Comment: @Robert TWRP  can decrypt it but the main problem is the password. The 3x3 pattern lock I had can be converted numerically, but there are conflicting sources on how Android arranges those numbers. If it's 123456789 you can easily draw the pattern, but if it's not then I have to figure it out. Is there a tool out there that would brute-force this? I assume with only 9 digits, even if you include 0, it's not that difficult?

Comment: https://twrp.me/faq/openrecoveryscript.html

Comment: @alecxs I saw it, but it's kinda greek to me. Not the best with this stuff, since it's probably a mounting issue

Comment: don't be lazy and read, nobody else will solve your issue. if you think its mounting issue you would see *Data successfully decrypted, new block device: '/dev/block/dm-0'* in recovery.log (and solution to mount read-only as descripted in links). but its more likely you are facing version binding (like JackSlater)

Comment: @alecxs I'm not being lazy. The particular question you linked has a different issue than the one I'm facing, as it seems he can't enter his password/pin to begin with. Also, it appears he's brute-forcing it anyway. In my case, I already know the password now, so it wouldn't be of help.

Comment: @alecxs I found the crypto footer but I'm confused which flags I need to look for

Comment: @alecxs Here's my thread, maybe you can help: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/how-to-recover-data-from-image.4247673/

Comment: @alecxs There must have been a misunderstanding, sorry. I've updated it with the footer.

Comment: @alecxs Thanks. I've uploaded the crypto footer file on XDA in the OP.

Comment: [what does hexdump/xxd say about dm-0? is it decrypted, can you see ext4/f2fs super magic?](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/how-to-recover-data-from-image.4247673/post-84712507)

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the type of encryption, if it's only 9 bits, it wouldn't take long to crack the encryption with the right tools, but to be honest, unless it's some REALLY valuable data, just format it. If you messed up the encryption though, it could have some bad sectors I wouldn't trust it for any data handling tasks.

Answer (score -1):

Remember: You don't need to decrypt it using TWRP, just format it on a PC with an SD card reader, format it while being booted into android, and there ya go, you have a new SD card ready to go.

Comment: What do you mean? Doesn't that erase it? I suppose there's a way to decrypt it from my PC, no?

Comment: guess he is talking about MicroSD Card (and of course formatting will delete all data on it)