# How to recover data from image?

Tags: twrp, xiaomi, android-10, disk-encryption

I have an encrypted complete `.img` of the `userdata` partition.
What tools or steps can I take, with the assistance of my phone, to decrypt this image?
It is my understanding that decrypting it without the phone is usually not possible. Given that I *do* have the phone however, what can I do?

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/234692