# How can I recover data from a phone MicroSD card?

Tags: sd-card

I have a Nokia 3 (Android) phone which uses a Micro SD card for additional storage. When I connect the phone to a Win 10 PC I see a CD-ROM added in File Explorer, containing a setup.exe file. If I click use USB to transfer files on the phone and  I see within Nokia 3 folder under This PC a folder called SD card. The properties of the SD card folder indicate the 25 GBytes have been used but within the folders visible  (Android, DCIM, Pictures and Download) there are only 703 MBytes of files which can be copied with File Explorer. The SD Card filesystem is shown as Generic hierarchical.It appears that most of the content is not visible to File Explorer.

If I remove the Micro SD card and try to view it by inserting an adapter and plugging the adapter into the SD socket on the computer, I get the message that the card format is not supported and I am asked if I wish to format the card.

If I try to use a Data Recovery product (Easus Data Recovery Pro) to try and retrieve the invisible files on the SD card it does not show the Nokia 3 folder under This PC so I cannot browse to the SD card folder.

Using Device Manager, Nokia 3 appears under portable devices and if I click Update Driver it indicates that the driver is MTP USB Device and it appears to be up to date.

If I plug the adapter into a 2013 Macbook Pro running Catalina (via an SD to USB adapter) I get the message that the card format is not supported.

How can I get access to the invisible files on the Micro SD card from the phone?

Comment: Linux will probably be able to access the card. Most likely it it formatted as `ext4` or similar.

Comment: If you don't have a nix machine, you can get ExtFS support on the Mac - https://www.paragon-software.com/home/extfs-mac/ - the free trial would let you test the theory.

Comment: It is the general concept of Android that users don't get access to their files if the app want to keep those files private. If the SD-card is formatted as internal storage then it is encrypted and it can only be read in the phone it had been formatted. The it doesn't matter which OS you use, they all will fail to read anything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Encryption on SD card. Not recovering data after crashing](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/219783/encryption-on-sd-card-not-recovering-data-after-crashing)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Backup/dump kernel image (and full ROM) without root for Mediatek Devices](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/203283/backup-dump-kernel-image-and-full-rom-without-root-for-mediatek-devices)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't access my phone memory suddenly after using SD card as internal memory](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/222394/cant-access-my-phone-memory-suddenly-after-using-sd-card-as-internal-memory)