# Final steps to repair corrupted F2FS SD Card - How to fix "can't read superblock"

Tags: linux, encryption, adoptable-storage

[I modified the question to reflect the progress]
The TLDR version is, the card is adopted storage that says corrupted f2fs.
I used the process detailed [Here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/135803/how-to-decrypt-the-corrupt-sd-card-formatted-as-internal-storage) but when I tried to mount the decrypted SD Card
I got "system call failed: Structure needs cleaning".

`#mount -t f2fs /dev/mapper/crypt1 /mnt/1/`
`mount: /mnt/1: mount(2) system call failed: Structure needs cleaning.`

When I tried to use fsck, I got "Error: In use by the system!"

`#fsck.f2fs /dev/sdc2`
`Error: In use by the system!`

Below is the info that may help you help me.[image: system call failed]
[image: Error:in use by the system]
[image: lsblk]
[image]
[image: I'm guessing this is the reason for corruption]

I'm not a linux expert, is this something I can correct?

After `fsck.f2fs /dev/mapper/crypt1; mount -t f2fs -o ro,norecovery /dev/mapper/crypt1 /mnt/1;`

I get:
[image: many more like this]
many more like this

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

I'm not sure what to do next; if I restore is the lost directory on the corrupted drive or the main drive?

Comment: *fsck.f2fs /dev/mapper/crypt1; mount -t f2fs -o ro,norecovery /dev/mapper/crypt1 /mnt/1;*

Comment: Thanks Alecxs,  I've added the results.  What do you think, is the data recoverable?

Comment: Now I get: 
`mount: /mnt/1: can't read superblock on /dev/mapper/crypt1.`

Comment: all I found is some explanation that you may face [Wandering Tree Problem](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/f2fs.txt) but the suggested attempt to cut out a certain offset from the header in order to realign super magic at offset 0x400 didn't solve the problem https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/371627