# How exactly does FBE's key derivation work?

Tags: encryption

These are the files that I know go into verifying a user's password:

```
/data/system/gatekeeper.password.key
/data/system/gatekeeper.pattern.key
/data/system/locksettings.db
/data/system/locksettings.db-shm
/data/system/locksettings.db-wal
```

I know that this is where the files used construct the FBE key are stored:

```
/data/misc/vold/user_keys/ce/0/current/version
/data/misc/vold/user_keys/ce/0/current/secdiscardable
/data/misc/vold/user_keys/ce/0/current/encrypted_key
/data/misc/vold/user_keys/ce/0/current/stretching
/data/misc/vold/user_keys/de/0/encrypted_key
/data/misc/vold/user_keys/de/0/stretching
/data/misc/vold/user_keys/de/0/keymaster_key_blob
/data/misc/vold/user_keys/de/0/secdiscardable
/data/misc/vold/user_keys/de/0/version
```

Although I'm told the encrypted FBE keys are stored in the above paths, these files seem related:

```
/data/system_de/0/spblob/0000000000000000.handle
/data/system_de/0/spblob/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.pwd
/data/system_de/0/spblob/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.secdis
/data/system_de/0/spblob/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.spblob
```

The `XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX` is a placeholder for a 16-character long hexadecimal "handle"; `0000000000000000.handle`, by contrast, is named exactly as it written. There are actually several sets of `pwd`/`secdis`/`spblob` files on my phone and two that are missing their `spblob` file. I'm not sure I'm supposed to have that many.

Over the pass few days, I've messed up my phone trying to get TWRP to decrypt my data. At first, after removing my password, I couldn't set another one as Settings would crash whenever I tried. I was able to fix it by renaming `locksettings.db`. I then went ahead and set and cleared several different (but very insecure) passwords/PINs, including my old one (which is secure). I'm unable to remember the order of events, but now I'm at a point where I get `Pixel is starting` whenever I swipe on my home screen after booting. I'm suspecting this has to do with it not being able to decrypt my FBE key. I'm wondering if through my combination of renaming files like `gatekeeper.*.key` and `locksettings.db` that the FBE key maybe was decrypted with the wrong key and then reencrypted with a different one.

I'd like to know what role the above files play in the encrypting my phone. I'd also like to know:

- What data from what sources is combined using what algorithms to decrypt the keys that encrypt my phone.
- What happens when the password is changed (e.g., what files are decrypted/reencrypted, whether the salt is changed, etc.).
- How the files `gatekeeper.*.key` and `locksettings.db` used in the process.
- Whether or not the FBE key ever changes with the password.

The purpose of all of this is to determine if the problem with my lies with the encryption key being wrong or if it's a matter of cleaning up the right files, and to get past the endless `Pixel is starting` message to my apps and content.

Comment: page 9+10 may give you some hints (just found this on google i do not understand everything) https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/e1cf/9ad5614f3a24b24088e4b22e9218f0abc3a0.pdf

Comment: @alexcs A factory reset will not suffice. I want my data that's on it.

Comment: bear in mind there is a 30 seconds timeout after x attempts (timeout may increase) and twrp will silently fail during this waiting period (even with the right pin) - it can even wipe your data (depends on gatekeeper settings and device)

Comment: furthermore i am not sure if /data/system ever was accessible (is this unencrypted area?)

Comment: @alexcs Why backup EFS? (And which metadata?)

Comment: I am not aware how it works for FBE but for FDE there is always a crypto footer, sometimes as file metadata on efs partition, sometimes as metadata partition, or concatenated to userdata partition (16384 bytes). Without this a backup becomes useless

Comment: @alexcs If the timeout is enforced by Android, then the timeout can be disabled by flashing a ROM that does not enforce it.

Comment: according to this fstab /metadata seems to be still relevant for FBE on some devices https://github.com/TeamWin/android_device_oneplus_guacamole/blob/android-9.0/recovery/root/etc/twrp.fstab

Comment: @alexcs Not true that a backup of FDE is useless without the "footer", which is just the FDE encryption key encrypted. If you have the [encryption key for the FDE](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/246742/344966) already, you don't need the footer.