# What is the /data/misc folder?

Tags: backup, recovery-mode, file-system

I recently ditched my phone's stock ROM for a lightweight custom one. After transferring my files over, reinstalling apps and reconfiguring settings, I wanted to perform a full backup of the  phone's "initial state", just in case anything goes wrong. So, I went ahead and rebooted to recovery mode.

I'm using **OrangeFox Recovery instead of TWRP** (for those who don't know, it's based on TWRP but with more support for encrypted internal storage partitions, *for my device at least*). I started the backup process from there, only to find out some time later that it failed when copying the `data` partition, and a status code at the end of the message screen that did not make that much sense. Pulling the log file using `adb pull` revealed that the copy process failed to add a file from a subdirectory in the `/data/misc` folder.

```
I:Error adding file '/data/misc/9i0eBx6h5AsCJUBmui5L4C/ADq3lG3ELF4NPOElzFdltC' to '/sdcard1/Fox/BACKUPS/...../data.ext4.win000'
```

A Google search did not come up with anything, only about specific files and subdirectories in the `/data/misc` folder.

So my questions are:

- What is the `/data/misc` folder (especially the random named subdirectories) used for?
- Since I cannot get the backup process complete at all because of this single error, is there a way to bypass or delete the file? (if it's not an important system file)

Comment: It contains random configuration settings: https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22%2Fdata%2Fmisc%22

Comment: Does this answer your question? [copy encrypted internal storage to pc ( in twrp mode )](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/221041/copy-encrypted-internal-storage-to-pc-in-twrp-mode)

Comment: @alecxs No, as I mentioned the OrangeFox backup situation just for context. My main question is about the `/data/misc` folder, as I stated above.

Comment: */data/misc/keystore
/data/misc/keychain
/data/misc/sms
/data/misc/textclassifier
/data/misc/wifi
/data/misc/profiles* are valid subdirectories, does one of these exist?

Comment: @alecxs I can see the contents of `/sdcard` from OrangeFox with no issues, but the subdirectories you mentioned in `/data/misc` are nowhere to be found, only the jumbled mess. So, the directory is encrypted. I'll forward this to the OrangeFox team. Thanks for your time!