# Xiaomi A2 stuck in a reboot loop because of data partition

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, fastboot, ota-update, partitions

I installed the October 2020 update for my Xiaomi A2, and then it entered a reboot loop, giving me a "Cannot load Android system" message.

Actually, when I boot up the phone, I automatically get to the recovery menu, which only gives me two options: wipe the data partition, or reboot. And rebooting sends me back to the recovery menu.

Here's what I did:

- First, using [fastboot](https://forum.xda-developers.com/mi-a2/how-to/fastboot-xiaomi-mi-a2-fastboot-images-t3824849), I reinstalled the entire OS except the data partition. That ended up in the same reboot loop.
- Then, using [TWRP](https://twrp.me/xiaomi/xiaomimia2.html) and executing it with `fastboot boot twrp-3.4.0-1-jasmine_sprout.img` I could `adb shell` into my device. From there I ran an `fsck -f` which did find a couple inode problem. But fixing those problems still did yield the same reboot loop.
- Using TWRP again, I locally cloned my data partition using `adb pull /dev/block/mmcblk0p69 data.img`, then I tried the "wipe the data partition" option. My phone did reboot properly, but of course it was reset to factory settings.

Question: is there a way I can restore my phone to a working state with my previous data? I really don't want to reconfigure all of it…

Also I don't really understand what's the problem with my original data partition. Is there a way to know why Android doesn't want to boot with it and why it sends me to the recovery partition?

More info:

- Running `fsck` on the local `data.img` says it has no error whatsoever
- I can mount the `data.img` and browse it. It's full of, well, files!

Comment: in twrp do *'adb pull /tmp/recovery.log'* and check if there is something like *"successfully decrypted"* - be aware for FBE you can't wipe *locksettings.db* https://android.stackexchange.com/q/216155

Answer (score 1):

So, here's the best I could do:

- Try to boot normally
- The phone will crash and try to reboot to the recovery partition.
- At that very instant, press volume down and power, so that it goes to fastboot instead
- From fastboot, launch TWRP with `fastboot boot twrp-3.4.0-1-jasmine_sprout.img`
- Once in TWRP, get a shell using `adb shell`
- Then from this shell, look at the file `/sys/fs/pstore/console-ramoops-0`. It contains the **previous** kernel boot log!

In my case, here's what the boot log contains : `init: Rebooting into recovery, reason: enablefilecrypto_faile`. So apparently something is wrong with [Androi File-Based Encryption](https://source.android.com/security/encryption/file-based)…