# Restoring the /data partition on Android 11 yields an unlockable phone

Tags: twrp, fastboot, encryption, restore

I have a Xiaomi A2 which went into a bootloop due to a buggy Android 11 OTA update. It's a bug in the update, and [a lot of people](https://forum.xda-developers.com/mi-a2/how-to/october-security-update-t4180697) are affected.
My phone really had a rather vanilla setup (original Android One ROM). The only exotic thing I did was to unlock the bootloader. Everything else is untouched.

When I installed the Oct 2020 OTA update (version V11.0.15.0.QDIMIXM) my phone went into a boot loop. So I booted on TWRP from fastboot, and using `adb pull /dev/block/mmcblk0p69 data.img` I got an entire disk image of my data partition on my PC.

Using fastboot I then flashed the previous known-working OS version (version V11.0.14.0.QDIMIXM) but then when I boot my phone I now have a weird problem: my PIN isn't recognized anymore! If I try and remove `/data/system/locksettings.db` from TWRP, then it does remove the PIN and I can "log in" with a swipe, but then the phone gives me a never ending spinner. I assume something is wrong with File-Based Encryption and the fact that I didn't provide a PIN.

Question: why is my PIN not working anymore? How can I get it to work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xiaomi A2 stuck in a reboot loop because of data partition](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/230668/xiaomi-a2-stuck-in-a-reboot-loop-because-of-data-partition)