# Recovering data from Android 10 (forgotten PIN)

Tags: security, twrp, data-recovery, encryption, android-10

Long story short: I have forgotten the PIN to my Android device, as it wasn't being used for a while.

Steps that I have tried/am trying/planning to try:

1. Brute forcing - I have been trying to brute force using another Android as a rubber ducky (via Nethunter). But for some reason, despite using the right kernel and everything, I couldn't enable HID support, so it's still under trial.
2. I tried force-enabling "Use fingerprint to unlock at first boot", and could unlock the screen, but of course, the data was still encrypted. But this did help me tweak helpful settings like: "Automatically unlock when correct PIN is entered". A question in mind here is: Would enabling this feature, indirectly mean, bypassing the time limitations on the entry of wrong PINs?
3. TWRP brute forcing - I have tried the tool by timvisee: apbf. But it has its limitations and also, again, (maybe I'm not doing it right) TWRP starts entering PINs via terminal, *but* it does so even if the code is not running on PC. Refer: https://github.com/timvisee/apbf
4. Most complicated way - I have not tried this in the right way, but I believe, by extracting the hash and salt (somehow), I could recover the PIN. In short, there is a loophole in the FBE (File-Based Encryption) implementation, but again, I don't know the how-to's. Refer: https://bits-please.blogspot.com/2016/06/extracting-qualcomms-keymaster-keys.html (Obsolete for Android 10)!

   Edit: Since I now know about CVE-2016-2431, I guess the required info can't be extracted by the old process. But again, I would like to know if there is a way to do it in Android 10
5. Making an image file - I have also thought of creating a raw image file of the /data partition in order to, either:

   1. Decrypt the partition later by using tools like hashcat (don't
      know exactly how) or
   2. Downgrade the Android to a lower version in order to decrypt it (again, don't know if it would work). (This won't work)

Information about Android:

- Device: RMX1921
- ROM: CUSTOM - ResurrectionRemix
- Android Version: Q/10
- Root status: Rooted (USB Debugging enabled)

That's all the information I can give right now, and if you could throw any light, I would be very grateful.

Lastly, we have working methods for lower Android versions, so I believe there is a working way for higher Android versions

P.S. - I am willing to try all the possible ways, in order to save my data

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127417/discussion-on-question-by-nurmengardian-recovering-data-from-android-10-forgott).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How exactly does FBE's key derivation work?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/216155/how-exactly-does-fbes-key-derivation-work)