# Reset failed decrypts counter Android 10

Tags: lock-screens, twrp, encryption, android-10

I have a locked phone (forgotten PIN). And due to many incorrect attempts, the gatekeeper timeout or cooldown period is stuck at 480s.

Is there any way to reset this failed decrypts counter, so that brute-forcing could be done feasibly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gatekeeper timeout. TWRP vs Lockscreen](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/239499/gatekeeper-timeout-twrp-vs-lockscreen)

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58590128#58590128