# Recovering forgotten lock

Tags: lock-screens, twrp, encryption, android-10, pattern-lock

I have forgotten a `3x3` pattern lock on my phone, luckily I do have TWRP.
Is there an easy way to brute-force it, then? I'm willing to wait a while if that's what it takes.
The reason I ask is because Android internally represents the lock as a PIN anyway, but the orientation isn't known hence the brute guess.
Any ideas? I'm not too familiar with fancy scripting/linux stuff honestly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gatekeeper timeout. TWRP vs Lockscreen](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/239499/gatekeeper-timeout-twrp-vs-lockscreen)

Comment: https://github.com/timvisee/apbf

Comment: https://github.com/Areizen/Frida-Pin-Bruteforce

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58596284#58596284