Recover userdata.bin file after bootloop issue - HONOR X8 (TFY-LX1)
So one week ago, my HONOR X8 (TFY-LX1) was entered into a bootloop issue, with everytime starting on safe mode. I searched a way to reset the device without losing data, but there is no simple way. It's for that I'm here to ask help at the community.
Indeed, I found the "EvoTool" by Evondt software within I have been able to extract data by fastboot read info tool. So I have on my pc 120GB of .bin files. Then I did a reset factory of the smartphone, and he was able to start normally.
But at this point, I'm struggling to restore userdata.bin (most important file for me) file that I saved before. Is-it just possible to import the file from my pc to the msartphone like a picture ? Someone has experienced this yet ?

As HONOR X8 contains 128GB flash memory the .bin files are most likely a partition dump. But I don't think you will be able to extract user data as those data is encrypted and backed by the hardware based security system. That means without loading the data correctly into that security system you don't get the keys necessary for decrypting the files. The largest file should be the user data partition. You may be able to mount it on a Linux system then you should see the encrypted filenames and file data (File Based Encryption).

There is a way to recover pictures by mounting on a linux device ?

As I said mounting shouldn't be the problem but the file names and their content will be encrypted. The encryption scheme is pretty complex: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/216155/2241
