# Recover deleted file on phone using FBE

Tags: data-recovery, encryption

Suppose we have a phone that:

- Runs Android 10.
- Uses file-based encryption.

Suppose one of the files is deleted, but the phone is immediately turned off so as to prevent the deleted file from being overwritten. Can the file be recovered and decrypted? What if the phone runs on Android 9?

Comment: Each file in FBE is encrypted by a different random crypto key that is stored encrypted by a different key into flash memory. I don't know how many data traces are left in file-system after deleting a file but even if we assume you would be able to fully recover the encrypted file data and th encrypted file key you would still need to decrypt the key which itself is derived multiple times from keys of a higher rank. And everything depends on a key stored protected in the CPU protected Trusted Execution Environment of your system. To my knowledge this should be next to impossible.

Comment: And to my knowledge there is no difference between FBE in Android 9 and 10.

Comment: There's [this answer about "recovering" the key for FBE](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/246742/44325), but I don't know if it may work as described.