# When crypt14 file of WhatsApp database is deleted automatically after 7 days, is it possible to recover it in Android 12? Are they permanently deleted

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, data-recovery

I downloaded some data recovery apps from Play Store. They failed to recover my deleted data, but they show some hidden WhatsApp files like `.status`.

Can they recover and steal my database file from them and upload it to their server?

Comment: Android 12 uses File based Encryption which makes file recovery extremely unlikely. See also comments here: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/246846/2241

Comment: @Robert, why not make it an answer?

Comment: @RohitGupta because I am not familiar with all the details of FBE encryption in combination with the used file-system and I don't want to make a definitive answer about a system that I only know in general.

Answer (score 1):

File recovery in newer Android OS is not possible.

Long Answer:

Most data recovery apps over the years have just failed to recover anything.

Some fake recovery by trying to get leftover data from cache or thumbnails and show them as recovered.
These apps claim to be able to recover deleted files. However, their effectiveness can vary, and they might require certain permissions or features that may not be available in Android's newer versions due to increased privacy and security measures.

Even if device is rooted any data recovery app needs to acquire permission with user intervention and can not directly access storage as low level disk access.

Comment: What if the file is automatically deleted for example whatsApp data base file which are automatically deleted after 7 days or when sender deleted photo from their side for everyone ? @mohsyn

Comment: 'Deletion' either automatically or manually is the same. The file entry is removed and the space it was occupying is marked as empty. So, theoretically, it can be recovered using advanced forensics but it is not possible for applications in newer devices to recover deleted media in normal scenarios.

Comment: Whether it is manually deleted or automatically deleted it is good to go or there is any difference between manually deletion and automatically deletion ( Automatically deleted as the database file in WhatsApp deleted automatically after 7 days ) are both action same or automatically deleted are not as good as manually deleted and one more thing if a FILE or PHOTO is automatically deleted in a device with FBE ( Android 12 ) it's encryption key is also Deleted with it or not @mohsyn

Comment: @Zai that makes it suitable for a new question. Post another question. Thanks!